# WCF RIA Generic Server-side query?

Tags: entity-framework, generics, wcf-ria-services

Is it possible to have a generic server-side query like the following?

```
public IQueryable<TContact> GetContactsOfType<TContact>()
  where TContact : Contact
{
  return ObjectContext.Contacts.OfType<TContact>();
}
```

I want RIA to recognize and regenerate for me this query at the client project.

**Note:** `Contact` is an abstract class that has some subclasses. I'm using Entity-Framework generated `EntityObject`s.

The error I get when I'm trying compile: `Type 'TContact' is not a valid entity type.  Entity types must have a default constructor.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default WCF RIA Services does not expose generic domain service methods for the client to call. RIA is strongly-typed to make it easier to reason about the behavior.

But there seems to be a workaround with defining your on DomainOperationEntry and a custom DomainServiceDescriptionProvider. Colin Blair posted an answer [here](https://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/223006/536469.aspx#536469). That seems to match what you are expecting.

**Update**: I tried what you want im my silverlight project and defined a generic query method on my domain service. The project compiles successfully but the generic parameter is ommited on the client side.

Comment: "Update: I tried...": Contact is an abstract class, I'm updating my answer adding the error I get.

Comment: You can only use concrete classes with WCF RIA; it will not marshal generics.

Comment: @Shimmy: Ok, i tried it with a non-stract class and doesn´t get an error.

Answer (score 1):

Instead, I would suggest to use Text Template of EF generator to create RIA Services operations for every entity. And use a pattern of name like how RIA Services uses "Get" `<Type>` Query, and other methods.